# How to separate meteor app as meteor server with GraphQL and ReactJS frontend runs separate to each other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, graphql, ddp

I have already an app in meteor/ReactJS with GraphQL. I am trying to separate in a way that the Meteor server and ReactJS frontend runs individually and how to link each other. Any example or reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- Pick a React build system, like CRA, Next.js, or Gatsby, and create a new site.
- Move your react code to that site.
- In the GraphQL client code setup, use Meteor server's GraphQL endpoint URL, like `meteorserver.site.com/graphql`